# Error installing JQ on windows

Tags: jq, chocolatey

I have been trying to install jq using chocoletey

However, when I run the following command, it fails.

```
choco install jq
```

Reading the log file, I see that it is pointing the Powershell script is pointing at a ULR that doesn't exist any more

> Attempt to get headers for
>   http://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/win64/jq.exe failed.

I tried update the powershell script but choco install still not working for me. Can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved it after reading details from the following pull-request.

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/959

The solution is to pass -version 1.5 to the install command. The following works just fine.

```
choco install jq --force -version 1.5
```

Comment: As of Oct 2, 2015, jq 1.5 is available directly: see https://chocolatey.org/packages/jq

Comment: Thank you. I can verify that it now works without providing a version

Answer (score 0):

During the moderation process, even if there is a newer version of the application hosted on chocolatey.org, doing `choco install <package name>` will only give you the latest moderated package.

However, if you are willing to accept the potential for a problematic package, you can always force the installation of an unmoderated package by specifying the version number in the install command, as you have done.

In this case, the unmoderated package actually fixed an issue with the moderated one, so it was safe to proceed with, but just take care when doing this, and only do it on a case by case basis, in the knowledge that an unmoderated package may actually change, based on comments which are raised during the moderation process.